# Is there a watch option when using rollup.js from the command line

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

I am using rollup.js to transpile the module dependencies from a file 'main.js'

```
rollup main.js
```

Is there a watch option to rerun the transpilation when a source file changes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of **v0.29** you can use `rollup --watch`.

---

No there is not yet ([command line options](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Command-Line-Interface#usage)). There has been an [issue opened for this just yesterday](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/284).

Rich-Harris wrote:

> Agree. We intend to add some functionality around incremental builds ([#191](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/191)), and this would go hand-in-hand with that. The goal would be for the incremental build stuff to be flexible enough to integrate with existing build systems, but I think it'd make sense for the CLI to support it out of the box:
>
> ```
> rollup -c --watch
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I will keep an eye on that issue

Comment: This is now shipped! https://github.com/rollup/rollup/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0290

Comment: @qubyte: Thanks! Updated the answer.